# How to use recursion to sum specific values in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-level object data with a structure similar to the window below.

I am trying to

- sum all the direct package values for the top users or say `parents`, only
- sum all the nested indirect package values from the `children` tree.

The final result is expected to be similar to:
`[{"sum_direct": 600},{"sum_indirect": 3000}]`

I need help to know what I'm not doing right:

```
function sumDirect($c) {
    if(count($c) > 0){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($c as $package) {
            $sum += $package['package']['direct'];
        }
    } else {
        $sum = 0;
    }
    return $sum;
}

function sumIndirect($c) {
    if(count($c) > 0){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($c as $package) {
            if(count($package['children']) > 0) {
                foreach ($package['children'] as $children){
                    $sum += $children['indirect'];
                    $sum += sumIndirect($children);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $sum = 0;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Sample input:

```
{
  "users": [{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ref_id": 1,
      "package": [{
          "name": "Basic"
        },
        {
          "direct": 200
        },
        {
          "indirect": 100
        }
      ],
      "children": [{
          "user_id": 58,
          "ref_id": 2,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 59,
          "ref_id": 2,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 111,
          "ref_id": 2,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 116,
          "ref_id": 2,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Diamond"
            },
            {
              "direct": 1000
            },
            {
              "indirect": 500
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 119,
          "ref_id": 2,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_id": 100,
      "ref_id": 1,
      "package": [{
          "name": "Basic"
        },
        {
          "direct": 200
        },
        {
          "indirect": 100
        }
      ],
      "children": [{
          "user_id": 101,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 102,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 103,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 104,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 105,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 106,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 107,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 108,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 109,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 110,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 117,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Diamond"
            },
            {
              "direct": 1000
            },
            {
              "indirect": 500
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 129,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Diamond"
            },
            {
              "direct": 1000
            },
            {
              "indirect": 500
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        },
        {
          "user_id": 130,
          "ref_id": 100,
          "package": [{
              "name": "Basic"
            },
            {
              "direct": 200
            },
            {
              "indirect": 100
            }
          ],
          "children": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Complete data at [users.json](https://github.com/bishoplee/mlu/edit/master/users.json)

Comment: So what is the question? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: @Bishoplee When a question is Unclear or there is no evidence of effort, you will find that the question gets voted down.  Please improve your question if you would like to prevent downvotes and run the chance of receiving upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion doesn't seem to be necessary for the "parent" direct values, so that can be done with a direct foreach loop.

The "children" indirect values require recursion.  I've elected to use `array_walk_recursive()` to access every "leaf node" in the array.  This will also store the parents' indirect values too, so I subtract those values after `array_walk_recursive()` is finished.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R827M))

```
$result['sum_direct'] = 0;
$result['sum_indirect'] = 0;
$parents_indirect = 0;
echo "<pre>";
$array = json_decode($json, true)['users'];
foreach ($array as $users) {
    $result['sum_direct'] += $users['package'][1]['direct'];
    $parents_indirect += $users['package'][2]['indirect'];
}
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($v, $k) use (&$result) {
        if ($k === 'indirect') {
            $result['sum_indirect'] += $v;
        }
    });
$result['sum_indirect'] -= $parents_indirect;

echo json_encode($result);
```

Output using your in-question data:

```
{"sum_direct":400,"sum_indirect":3000}
```

Output using your full json from github:

```
{"sum_direct":600,"sum_indirect":22400}
```

Comment: You've been a great source of encouragement. Looking at the demo you created, what can be the likely impact on the server with a large data since this is expected to grow over time?

Comment: Are you happy with this solution or would you rather have a custom-coded recursive call? Are the results correct?  Questions are most-clear when the EXACT expected output is stated in the question.

Comment: The results are correct though but what do you imply with custom-coded recursive call?

Comment: I have no way of guessing the size of your data over time.  I also haven't benchmarked my solution on the sample data.  Once you have a working solution,  you can post your code on CodeReview and ask about optimization.  If you are truly concerned about performance, my first recommendation is to refine your data structure because it is currently bloated with too many levels.

Comment: Your `sum_indirect()` is a custom function.  I used a native recursive function.

Comment: To clarify what I mean about "level bloat", your array has indexed subarrays, but there is no benefit.  I think your data is best stored as fully-associative.

Comment: 1. the data structure is to handle a multi-level user application based on referrals so I suppose there may be need to stop the inner levels at a point, say level 5, to avoid the bloat arising from deeper levels. What's your thought on this?

2. can you suggest a best fully-associative structure for my current data?

Comment: Okay, a few points... If you are going to "cap" the number of children of a parent, then you no longer _need_ to resort to recursion -- you could write _5_ static loops.  Truncating the data after an arbitrary number of levels will, of course, impact data accuracy but whether of not this is damaging to your project is a decision for you to make.  Regarding refining your data structure, I'll offer some principles...  1. use consistent data types for reused elements e.g. `children = 0` and `children = array()` are different types which complicate processing.

Comment: If there is no data (`children = 0`) just omit the declaration entirely.  If your data is going to contain user-identified data, remove the top level association and just use the userids as the top level keys.  The `package` data doesn't seem to need two levels, so flatten as an associative array.  https://3v4l.org/8K0ja <-- this is just something that I mocked up, it might have typos in it.

Comment: the tips came in quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way could be based on a couple for foreach one nested  the other

```
$result['sum_direct'] = 0;
$result['sum_indirect'] = 0;

$myArray = json_decode($myJsonString, TRUE)
  foreach($myArray['users'] as  $value){
  $result['sum_direct'] += $value['package']['direct'];
  foreach($value['children']['package'] as  $value2){
    $result['sum_indirect']  += $value2['indirect'];
  }
}

$jsonResult= json_encode($result);
```

Comment: @mickmackusa I updated with the attempts made at getting the summations.